# Upload and save large file into database as a varbinary

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm having a problem with PHP and my SQL Server.

When I try to save a file into the database as a `varbinary(MAX)` type, it works perfectly, but when I try to save a file of 180k or more in the result, I only get part of the image:

```
$handle = @fopen($fileTmpName, 'rb');
if ($handle)
{
    $content = @fread($handle, filesize($fileTmpName));        
    $content = bin2hex($content);
    @fclose($handle);
}
$select = mssql_query("EXEC [DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name] @Data = ".$content."");
$result = mssql_fetch_array($select);
$_SESSION['fileContent'] = $result['Data'];

<img src="../applications/framework/images.php" />
```

`image.php` file contains the following:

```
header("Content-type: ".$fileType);
header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$fileName);
echo $_SESSION['fileContent'];
```

As a result, I only get part of the image.

I mean that it only loads the first part of the real image. It seems that it inserts only the first part of the content into the database instead of all of it.

How can this be solved?

Comment: does your php script time out while uploading the file?

Comment: Is there any reason in particular you are storing the image in the database, instead of as a file? In most cases, storing a file as a normal file is more efficient than storing it in a database.

Comment: If I had a dollar for every question on SO asked about storing images in a database . . . .

Comment: There is no any problem in time upload, it does successful, there is no any error visible, the problem is after that when I want to get it from the database I get only the part of the image

Answer (score 0):

check the table structure. It might be the column might not be set up as a var(max)

Comment: The column type for the image is varbinary(MAX).

Comment: I don't think the problem is the type, because when I  save small image it does work perfect, because of the small size of the image it loads entirely.